# Splice function inside of map() only delete half of array

Tags: angular, typescript

i have an array with 146 objects(for now) and an id which is coming with router.
i want to delete objects if object.id is not equal to id.
I wrote an function for that but its only work for half of the array. this function was working well before i add these splice.
My code;

```
getFullData(){
var fullData = [OBJECTS].sort(function(a,b){if(a.date<b.date)return 1; if(a.date > b.date) return -1})} //sorting

fullData.map(val=>{
  Object.assign(val, {dataType:this.getDateType(val.date)}); //this line not about these problem
  if (val.device !== this.id) {
    fullData.splice(fullData.indexOf(val), 1);
  }  
});
return fullData;
}
```

this all id's on objects are same for now. When i route different id with router it must delete all of them but only delete 73 object.

Comment: can you please provide `https://stackblitz.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looping the same array you are splicing, better would be to use a filter before the map:

```
fullData = fullData
  .filter((val) => val.device !== this.id)
  .map((val) => {...val, dataType: this.getDateType(val.date) });
```

If performance is an issue, and you don't want to loop twice, you can all do it inside the filter:

```
fullData = fullData
  .filter((val) => {
    if (val.device !== this.id) {
      return false;
    }

    val.dataType = this.getDateType(val.date);

    return true;
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

use `filter` instead of splice in map.

```
var newFullData = fullData.filter(val=> val.device === yourId)

//newFullData array will contain only those values of fullData where object with device value equals to yourId
```

Read more about [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)